# Pros/cons of view being responsible for reading/writing data

Tags: model-view-controller, mvvm, view, model, mvp

I have a view that I may use in any number of applications. It's a special viewer for a kind of data type. It contains a special reader for files that pertain to this data type and it can write them. What are the pros and cons of doing it this way? In a recent project, the MVVM proponents argued the view must be "dumb". This makes no sense because how can it be dumb if it is a narrowly specialized viewer? Is it possible that MVVM comes from the web world where viewers are simple? Anyway, the MVVM proponents also believed any data that goes into a view must be conditioned first e.g. converted to HTML, if the view is a webview. Seems like overkill. Why do that?

Answer (score 0):

The concept of MVVM is to separate business logic (model) from view. In your case the reader writer should be in the model code. The Pro is that if you at any point want to make changes to the view side you can do so without changing or moving around code that does the actual data exchange (read write).

It also means that you can write tests against your model and if you change your view the model and test code will be left untouched.

Con with MVVM is that it adds some extra layer of code, it can add some development time (at least when one is new to MVVM) and in the beginning one may feel a bit locked by follow a pattern.

In the end I usually find the Pros to be bigger. One get a good and well thought through Design, separation of concerns for the codebase, easy to test different parts and the day you get a request for modifying or extending the control it will be much easier.